# Function stored as state in a context provider is only updating once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, next.js

I'm using Next.js and Typescript, but I don't think that's relevant to the problem here so I titled it as a general React problem. Also I've scoured Stack Overflow for hours on this, I'm certain it's not a duplicate of any other problems I've read pertaining to mine.

For context: I have a `<Grid>` component that generates multiple `<Cell>` components that holds images.

The premise is simple: cell gets clicked, modal opens and the user selects an image, then it updates the cell's image src prop.

Cell.tsx:

```
export default function Cell() {
  const [src, setSrc] = useState<string>(`https://picsum.photos/seed/${Math.random()}/1000`);
  const context: IModalContext = useContext(ModalContext);

  function onSrcReceived(newSrc: string) {
    setSrc(newSrc);
  }

  return (
    <div
      className={styles.cell}
      onClick={() => {
        context.openModal(onSrcReceived);
      }}
    >
      {src && <Image layout="fill" quality={1} src={src} alt="random pic" />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

As you see, the cell calls the context's openModal() function, passing its onSrcReceived() callback as a prop.

ModalContext.tsx:

```
function ModalContextWrapper({ children }: Props) {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [providedCallback, setProvidedCallback] = useState<Function>();

  function onAlbumSelected(src: string) {
    if (!providedCallback) throw new Error("Callback not provided!");
    providedCallback(src);
  }

  const value: IModalContext = {
    openModal: (_cb: Function) => {
      setShowModal(true);
      setProvidedCallback(() => _cb);
    },
  };
  return (
    <ModalContext.Provider value={value}>
      <AlbumPickerModal
        showModal={showModal}
        setShowModal={setShowModal}
        onAlbumSelected={onAlbumSelected}
      />
      {children}
    </ModalContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

My ModalContext wraps the entire application. In summary of what it's doing: it receives the request to open the modal, then stores the cell's callback in local state. When the user selects an album cover from the `<AlbumPickerModal>`, it fires the `onAlbumSelected()` callback with the src as a prop.

The ModalContext's `onAlbumSelected()` works as intended. It receives the src value and fires the cell's callback, stored in local state as `providedCb`, with the new src as a prop. This all works correctly, but only for the first request. Every cell I attempt to update after that simply only updates the first updated cell. It's as though the `setProvidedCb()` is only setting the callback ONCE, and not for any future updates.

I've been banging my head on this for hours. If I am implementing this modal input mechanism entirely wrong, please enlighten me of an easier solution. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think you are correct in that this isn't a Typescript or Nextjs issue. Think you could create a *running* codesandbox demo of the code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: Sure, here it is:https://codesandbox.io/s/function-in-state-not-updating-demo-bjnkc5?file=/src/styles.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the modal is holding on to a stale `providedCallback` state reference. Clicking the "search" button ***then*** selecting a new image seems to resolve the reference issue, I suspect due to a rerender occurring with "capturing" the new callback.

Instead of storing the passed callback in state which triggers a rerender, use a React ref instead.

ContextWrapper.tsx

```
function ModalContextWrapper({ children }: Props) {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const providedCallbackRef = useRef<Function>(); // (1) <-- React ref

  function onAlbumSelected(src: string) {
    if (!providedCallbackRef.current) { // (3a) <-- check ref
      throw new Error("Callback not provided!");
    }
    providedCallbackRef.current(src); // (3b) <-- invoke callback
  }

  const value: IModalContext = {
    openModal: (_cb: Function) => {
      setShowModal(true);
      providedCallbackRef.current = _cb; // (2) <-- save callback reference
    }
  };

  return (
    <ModalContext.Provider value={value}>
      <AlbumPickerModal
        showModal={showModal}
        setShowModal={setShowModal}
        onAlbumSelected={onAlbumSelected}
      />
      {children}
    </ModalContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit function-stored-as-state-in-a-context-provider-is-only-updating-once]

### Side Note:

I noticed in several of your components you are saving JSX into your state. This is an anti-pattern that often leads to stale enclosures of state, among other issues. State should only store the data and the rendered JSX should be ***derived*** from the state. In other words, the rendered UI is a function of `state` in React.

Example with `Grid`:

Current:

```
export default function Grid({ cols, rows }: IProps) {
  const total = cols * rows;
  const [cells, setCells] = useState<JSX.Element[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // get array of new cells
    const newCells = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < total; i++) {
      const x = <Cell key={i} />;
      newCells.push(x);
    }
    setCells(newCells);
  }, [rows, cols]);

  const gridStyle = {
    display: "grid",
    gridTemplateColumns: `repeat(${cols}, auto)`,
    width: "20rem"
  };

  return <div style={gridStyle}> {cells} </div>;
}
```

Correct:

```
export default function Grid({ cols, rows }: IProps) {
  const [cells, setCells] = useState<number[]>(
    Array.from({ length: cols * rows }, (_, i) => i)
  );

  const gridStyle = {
    display: "grid",
    gridTemplateColumns: `repeat(${cols}, auto)`,
    width: "20rem"
  };

  return (
    <div style={gridStyle}>
      {cells.map((i) => (
        <Cell key={i} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

It is entirely possible that your original `providedCallback` state implementation was correct, but was getting messed up by the modal or some component above it being stored in a React state and resulting in a stale enclosure as I described.

Comment: Can't thank you enough for the time you took on this problem! Your answer was very in-depth and I learned a lot. I had no idea storing JSX in state was an anti-pattern.